# Calculate the volume enclosed by the paraboloid $f(x,y)=1-\frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{2}y^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume

> Calculate the volume enclosed by the paraboloid $f(x,y)=1-\frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{2}y^2$ and the plane $z=0$, when $f(x,y)$ is defined in $D=[0,1]\times [0,1]$.

I used polar coordinates and I had the following integral,

$$\int _{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int _{0}^{1} \left(1-\frac{1}{2}r^2\right)\,dr\,d\theta =\dfrac{3\pi}{16}$$

Is it right?

Comment: No it isn't right.  You have a *two*-dimensional integral when the problem is *three*-dimensional ("paraboloid"... $z$ as a function of $x$ and $y$...).

Comment: I see that it is wrong, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int\limits_{x=0}^1 \int\limits_{y=0}^1 \int\limits_{z=0}^{1 - x^2/2 - y^2/2} 1\ dx\ dy\ dz = \frac{2}{3}$$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With Cartesian coordinates, volume is
$$\int _{0}^{1}\int _{0}^{1}\int _{0}^{1-\frac12 x^2-\frac12 y^2}dzdydx=0.7$$

Comment: Thank you very much, the result seems to be the same.

Comment: Why that upper limit on the $y$ integral?

Comment: @M.Foster:  Your "volume" is two-dimensional, while the problem is three-dimensional... right?

Answer (score 0):

In this case cartesian coordinates are convenient.

Using polar cordinates the correct set up should be

$$\int_0^{\frac \pi 2} d\theta  \int_0^1 dz \int_0^{\sqrt{2-2z}}rdr-2\int_0^{\frac \pi 4}\int_{\frac{1}{\cos \theta}}^\sqrt 2 d\theta\int_0^{1-\frac {r^2}2}dz=\frac \pi 4-2\left(\frac \pi 8-\frac1{3}\right)=\frac23$$

- [first integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint%20r%20dr%20dt%20dz%20r%3D0..%282-2z%29%5E.5%20t%3D0..pi%2F2%20z%3D0..1%20)
- [second integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint%20r%20dz%20dr%20dt%20t%3D0..pi%2F4%20r%3D%281%2F%28cos%20t%29%29..2%5E.5%20%20z%3D0..%281-r%5E2%2F2%29%20)